# is it possible to use constants in annatation in codeception example

Tags: php, testing, annotations, codeception

With codeception is there a way to use constants ( or variables) using the @example annotation ?
I know that we can use doctrine style annotation.

> Data is defined via the @example annotation, using JSON or Doctrine-style notation (limited to a single line). Doctrine-style
>
> ```
> class PageCest
> {
>  /**
>   * @example(url="/", title="Welcome")
>   * @example(url="/info", title="Info")
>   * @example(url="/about", title="About Us")
>   * @example(url="/contact", title="Contact Us")
>   */
>   public function staticPages(AcceptanceTester $I, \Codeception\Example $example)
>   {
>     $I->amOnPage($example['url']);
>     $I->see($example['title'], 'h1');
>     $I->seeInTitle($example['title']);
>   }
> }
> ```

But using a constant which is working in doctrine doesn't seems to work here

```
/**
 * @example(url=Class::Constant, title="Welcome")
 */
```

is there a way to achieve this to run multiple test examples but use constants or variables to provide the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to do that directly like doctrine's implementation.
the workaround I found is to pass the constant name as a string .

```
/**
 * @example(url="MyConstantName", title="Welcome")
 */
```

and then within the code use the constant function to find your constant value.

```
constant('Full\Namespace\MyClass::' . $example['MyConstantName'])
```